# Continuous $f$, $\sup_{x,y\in R^m}\|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)\|<\infty$, then exist only one real matrix $A$, such that $f(x)-Ax$ is bounded.

Tags: analysis

**Problem:**

f is a continuous function, $f: \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$, $\sup_{x,y\in R^m}\|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)\|<\infty$, there exist only one real matrix $A$, such that $f(x)-Ax$ is bounded.

**My thoughts 1:**

$\sup_{x,y\in R^m}\|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)\|:=M<\infty$, then $\|f(2x)-2f(x)\|<M$, $\|f(3x)-f(2x)-f(x)\|<M$, so $\|f(3x)-3f(x)\|\leq\|f(3x)-f(2x)-f(x)+f(2x)-2f(x)\|\leq2M$, so by reduction, we have $\|f(nx)-nf(x)\|<(n-1)M$, then $\|\frac{f(nx)}{n}-f(x)\|<(1-\frac{1}{n})M$

I want to fix $x$ and let $n \to \infty$, but is hard to show $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(nx)}{n}$ exists.

**My thoughts 2:**

If we **assert** $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(nx)}{n}$ exists, define $G(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(nx)}{n}$, I want to show $G(x)$ is linear.

If so, $G(x)=Ax$, then the $A$ is what we want.

---

My thoughts:
The limit may not exist.

Three steps:
1.$R^1$ case

2.each element in $R^n$ is actually the $R^1$ case

3.different elements are "independent"

Comment: Intuitively, $Ax$ may be an asymptotic “plane”

Comment: Is $f(x)-Ax$ supposed to hold for fixed $A$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, or a fixed $x$ and some $A$?

Comment: @V.S.e.H for all $x \in R^n$, only one $A$

Comment: We can prove that $\|f(tx)-tf(x)\|= O(t)$, but not sure how that helps.

Comment: One way to go about for the $n=m=1$ case is by observing that the integer-indexed sequence $\{f(n)\}$ is sub-additive in the limit $n\to\infty $ and it's well-known that for such sequences,  $\dfrac{f(n)}{n}$ converges as $n\to\infty.$ Then appeal to continuity to get the convergence of $f(t)/t$. There is also the continuous version directly but that requires the function to only take non-negative arguments. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us prove that $f_n(x) = \frac{f(2^nx)}{2^n}$ converges for all $x$ toward some $L(x)$. A powerful tool to obtain limits in metric spaces is completeness.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We have,
$$
\|f_{n + 1}(x) - f_n(x)\| = \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}}\|f(2^{n + 1}x) - 2f(2^nx)\| \leqslant \frac{M}{2^{n + 1}},
$$
because $2^{n + 1}x = 2^nx + 2^nx$ and $2f(2^nx) = f(2^nx) + f(2^nx)$. It proves that the series of the $f_{n + 1} - f_n$ is normally convergent (the series of the $\frac{M}{2^{n + 1}}$ converges). By completeness of the space of bounded continuous functions with the sup norm, the series of the $f_{n + 1} - f_n$ converges, thus $f_n - f_0 \rightarrow f_\infty$ where $f_\infty$ is a bounded continuous function. Let $L = f_\infty + f_0 = f_\infty + f = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n$ (the limit is uniform). As $f_\infty$ is bounded, $f - L = -f_\infty$ is bounded too.

We only have left to show that $L$ is linear. Indeed, for all $x,y$ and all $n$,
$$
\|f_n(x + y) - f_n(x) - f_n(y)\| = \frac{1}{2^n}\|f(2^nx + 2^ny) - f(2^nx) - f(2^ny)\| \leqslant \frac{M}{2^n}
$$
When $n \rightarrow +\infty$, we deduce that $L(x + y) = L(x) + L(y)$. Knowing that $L$ is continuous, it is enough to conlude that it is linear. For this, begin by proving that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x$, $L(nx) = nL(x)$, then extend it to $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then prove that for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and all $x$, $L(qx) = qL(x)$, and finally conlude using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and continuity of $L$.

Therefore, $L(x) = Ax$ for some matrix $A$ and $f(x) = L(x) + f_\infty(x) = Ax + \mathrm{O}(1)$ because $f_\infty$ is bounded.

Comment: (+1) This is so clever!

Comment: Thanks ! By the way, it also works the same in Banach spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a tedious proof. Assume wlog that $\sup_{x,y\in\mathbb{R}^m}\|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)\| = 1$.

**Lemma 1**

> Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb{R}^m, 1 < k$, then
> $\left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i)\right\| < k-1$

*Proof*: We use induction. The base case $k=2$ is just the given condition. Assume as induction hypothesis that $\left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}f(x_i)\right\| < k-2$. Then
$$
\left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^k f(x_i)\right\|= \left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\right) - f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_i\right) +f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^k f(x_i)\right\|\leq\\
\leq \left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}f(x_i)\right\| + \left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\right) - f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_i\right) - f(x_k)\right\| <k-2 + 1=k-1,
$$
using the induction hypothesis and the base case, so the general case is proven by induction.

**Lemma 2**

> For positive integer $p$ and a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, we have
> $\|f(-px)+pf(x)\| < p+1.$

*Proof*: Note that $\|f(0)\| = \|-f(0)-f(x)+f(x)\|\leq 1$, using the main condition. Thus using **Lemma 1**:
$$
\|f(-px)+pf(x)\|\leq \|f(0)-f(-px)-pf(x)\|+\|f(0)\| < p+1.
$$

**Lemma 3**

> Let $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_k\in\mathbb{R}$ be scalars and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ vectors, then $\left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^kt_ix_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^kt_if(x_i)\right\| < 2k - 1 + \sum_{i=1}^k |t_i|$.

*Proof*: First we prove the case $k=1$. Let $p \neq 0$ and $q > 0$ be integers. If $p > 0$, then using **Lemma 1** we have that
$$
\left\|\frac{p}{q}f(x)-f\left(\frac{p}{q}x\right)\right\|=
\frac{1}{q}\left\|pf(x)-qf\left(\frac{p}{q}x\right)\right\|=
\frac{1}{q}\left\|pf(x) - f(px)+f(px)-qf\left(\frac{p}{q}x\right)\right\|\leq\\
\leq \frac{1}{q}\left\|f(px) - pf(x) \right\| + \frac{1}{q}\left\|f(px) - qf\left(\frac{px}{q}\right)\right\| < \frac{p-1}{q} + \frac{q-1}{q} < p/q + 1. \tag{1}\label{ineq:1}
$$
On the other hand if $p < 0$, then using **Lemma 2** we have similarly as above that:
$$
\left\|\frac{p}{q}f(x)-f\left(\frac{p}{q}x\right)\right\| < \left(\frac{|p|+1}{q} + \frac{q-1}{q} \right)M < \frac{|p| + 1}{q} + 1 \tag{2}\label{ineq:2}
$$
Now let $\frac{p_1}{q_1},\frac{p_2}{q_2},\ldots$ be a rational sequence that converges to some nonzero $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then by continuity of $f$ and of the norm, we have that
$$
\left\|\frac{p_i}{q_i}f(x)-f\left(\frac{p_i}{q_i}x\right)\right\| \to \|tf(x)-f(tx)\|,
$$
while the bounds $\eqref{ineq:1}$ and $\eqref{ineq:2}$ also converge to $|t|+1$, thus proving the case $k=1$.

Now we prove the general case $k>1$:
$$
\left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^kt_ix_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^kt_if(x_i)\right\|\leq
\sum_{i=1}^k\| f(t_ix_i) - t_if(x_i) \| + \left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^kt_ix_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^kf(t_ix_i)\right\| <\\< k-1+\sum_{i=1}^k |t_i|+1 = 2k + \sum_{i=1}^k |t_i|,
$$
using **Lemma 1** and the case $k=1$, which completes the proof.

**Solution to the problem**

First we prove that the sequence $\{f(tx)/t\}$ is convergent for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, where $t$ is a positive integer. Indeed given any $\epsilon > 0$ and $N > 2\epsilon^{-1}$, we have for all positive integers $t,s > N$ that
$$
\left\| \frac{f(tx)}{t} - \frac{f(sx)}{s} \right\| = \frac{1}{ts}\left\| sf(tx) - tf(sx)\right\| \leq \frac{1}{ts}\left\| f(tsx) - tf(sx)\right\| + \frac{1}{ts}\left\| f(tsx) - sf(tx)\right\| < \frac{t+s-2}{ts} < \epsilon
$$
using **Lemma 1**, so $\{f(tx)/t\}$ is Cauchy, and hence convergent since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete.

Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$, and let $A_t = \begin{pmatrix}f(te_1)/t&f(te_2)/t&\cdots&f(te_m)/t\end{pmatrix}$. If $x=\sum_{i=1}^m x_i e_i$, then by **Lemma 3** we have
$$
\|f(x)-A_tx\|=\left\|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i e_i \right)-\sum_{i=1}^m x_i\frac{f(te_i)}{t}\right\| < 2m - 1 + \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^m|x_i|.
$$
Taking the limit, setting $A = \lim_{t\to\infty}A_t$ and using continuity gives us the result.

Comment: how does the Lemma 3 imply the limit of $\|f(x) - f(tx)/t\|$ again ?

Comment: @dezdichado Sorry, that is indeed a mistake. We have
$$
\|f(mx)/m - f(nx)/n)\| = \frac{1}{mn}\|nf(mx) - mf(nx)\| \leq \frac{1}{mn}\|f(mnx)- nf(mx)\| + \frac{1}{mn}\|f(mnx) - mf(nx)\| < \frac{2+m+n}{mn}
$$ using said lemma (or lemma 1). Thus the sequence $\frac{f(nx)}{n}$ is Cauchy, hence convergent. Or use the result that you have posted in the comment to the OP.